# DNS Wildcard With Suffix in Subdomain

Tags: dns

Is it possible to have a DNS wildcard with a suffix in the subdomain?

Example:

```
A Record:
*foo.example.com -> 192.0.2.1

Resolves:
test1-foo.example.com
test2-foo.example.com
test3-foo.example.com
```

Is this possible? Or, does the wildcard require the entire subdomain like `*.example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a DNS wildcard with a suffix in the subdomain?

No.

Wildcards do not work that way.

See RFC8499 and RFC4592 for all explanations, especially the second one.

> 2.1.1.  Wildcard Domain Name and Asterisk Label
>
> A "wildcard domain name" is defined by having its initial (i.e.,
> leftmost or least significant) label be, in binary format:
>
> ```
>  0000 0001 0010 1010 (binary) = 0x01 0x2a (hexadecimal)
> ```
>
> The first octet is the normal label type and length for a 1-octet-
> long label, and the second octet is the ASCII representation [RFC20]
> for the '*' character.

So in short `*foo` is **NOT** a wildcard per DNS rules.